# Tool Like Argument Principle For Real-Valued Functions

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots, real-numbers, meromorphic-functions

The [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) gives a way of numerically counting the number of roots-poles ($Z-P$) of a meromorphic function in a contour. I was wondering, can the Argument Principle (or some other tool like it) be used to count $Z-P$ (or just $Z$) of a real -valued function $f$, that is neither holomorphic nor meromorphic, but does satisfy certain conditions (like being $p$-times differentiable, being continuous, etc.) The tool should only count $Z-P$ (or $Z$) within a shape defined in the real plane.

Comment: Smooth functions are too flexible. What they do at one place doesn't tell you anything about what they do at another. They can take any values and derivatives that you want where you want [within reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem).

Comment: @conditionalMethod So how do I limit it?

Comment: @conditionalMethod However, my function is not infinitely differentiable, just $p$-times.

Comment: If you have a concrete problem then ask the exact problem that you have. If you don't know the answer to your concrete problem, how do you expect to be capable to successfully transforming it into a meaningful question by removing information?

Comment: @conditionalMethod No, I was just generalizing the problem.

Comment: You must be really sure of what you know to be saying "No". The worst king of learner. Those who don't know, but think they do. Bye.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I was just saying "No", I didn't have any specific problem in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly not... I suppose the reason is that there are "too many" smooth functions. For instance, suppose you know what $f$ is on $(-\infty,a)$ and $(a+\epsilon, \infty)$, then there actually exist infinitely many smooth functions that agree with $f$ on those intervals but are different. Whereas if you work with holomorphic functions, if $f=g$ on ANY collection of points that accumulates in your domain $\Omega$, then $f\equiv g$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the functions that can work, though?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: It is perhaps possible...but it would certainly require modding out by some sort of equivalence relation. But this would have to be such a strong relation that your question then looses almost all meaning. There really are just too many smooth functions.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for other answers before accepting yours.

Comment: However, my function is not infinitely differentiable, just $p$-times.

Comment: If you allow even more functions than just smooth ones, then the problem becomes worse.

Comment: No, I'm not allowing smooth functions, but functions only $p$-times differentiable (and no more).

Comment: There is still no hope. This may demonstrate: Let $A=\{ f\in C^p, \; f\not\in C^{p+1}\}$. Then if you take any continuous $\phi$ and integrate it $p$ times, this is in $A$. But there are WAY too many continuous functions to even hope to make any sort of claim.